How to cite a website title with non-standard capitalization in APA style?
I am attempting to cite a website title with non-standard capitalization. I know that you would lowercase a website title that is presented completely in capital letters, but I am unsure as to how I would write a reference citation for a title with the format of something like "LightsWeekly", which has two words capitalized in title case and combined into one word. Can someone please give me assistance on how to do this?

Retaining the stylized capitalization seems sensible, and would follow the logic for brand names.

You should present the title of the website as it is officially styled, without modifying its capitalization or spacing, in exactly the same way as you would if the title was "Compleetlee Ronglee Spelt". The given title is the title!
In the case of something like LightsWeekly you are treating the word as a proper noun, just as you would a brand name such as RollaDoor (for roller garage doors).

Website names are actually case sensitive. I remember I cited a website in my article with wrong capitalization, and it was not accessible. My understanding is only the domain names are case-insensitive, everything that goes after the domain name is case-sensitive.

It seems you're mixing up the name of the website and the URL. APA style requires both. Part of the URL can indeed be case-sensitive.

@Anyon : I stand corrected. Looks like I misunderstood the term "website name". But I think it is important that web page names are case sensitive.
